# IEEE 802.11 standard on channels

Tags: wifi, linux, 802.11

Could someone please help me find (page#) where in the [IEEE 802.11](http://standards.ieee.org/about/get/802/802.11.html) standard it directly says that Access Points are responsible for choosing the channel/frequency to be used and not clients. I know it's in there somewhere but I can't find where it says that in plain text and was hoping maybe someone on here is more familiar with the standard may know.

Comment: p.s. my marketing team is literately telling me we need to fix this feature, ie. clients choose wifi channel because my predecessor has this option in the gui but it doesn't work(wpa_sup) and now doesn't believe me when I say you can't do this, hope you enjoy that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Channel usage information is provided by the AP to the non-AP STA to recommend channels for
>   noninfrastructure networks or an off-channel TDLS direct link. The non-AP STAs can use the channel usage
>   information as part of channel selection processing for a noninfrastructure network or an off-channel TDLS
>   direct link.

At page 58.

> The AP Channel Report element contains a list of channels where a STA is likely to find an AP.

At page 580.

> The Channel Switch Announcement element is used by an AP in a BSS, a STA in an IBSS, or a mesh STA
>   in an MBSS to advertise when it is changing to a new channel and the channel number of the new channel.

At page 490.

Source: [IEEE-802.11](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee802/download/802.11-2012.pdf)